# How can I tell if files from coldpi are backdoored?

Tags: armory, coldstorage, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install Armory on a Raspberry Pi.

I have tried installing the [Offline Bundle] for RaspberryPi (armhf) from http://bitcoinarmory.com but I'm getting compile errors on Raspbian. I also tried to update the g++ version with no luck.

So, I want to try with the files from http://coldpi.com/manuals/install.html

How to I know if these files are safe to use?

Comment: Not sure if this is a true answer, but does this help?
https://bitcoinarmory.com/tutorials/armory-basics/verify-download/